# Unable to create a bare git repository

Tags: linux, git

My git version is 1.5.0.6.

I want to create a bare git repository called sample.git.

I tried all sorts, but it failed:

Try 1:

Gives a usage statement but no git created

```
git init --bare sample.git 
usage: git-init [--template=<template-directory>] [--shared]
```

Try 2: (using git-init not git init)

```
$ git-init --bare sample.git
usage: git-init [--template=<template-directory>] [--shared]
```

Try 3: Create a directory sample and then run same command, but still same output and git repository not created.

Please help me.

Comment: Was your first try `git init` or `git-init`? What does `git version` tell you?

Comment: My git repository version is 1.5.0.6, already mentioned on top :)

Comment: Why do you call that a "repository version"? I am interested in the version of the binary in your PATH. Also, could you please still answer both questions?

Comment: git --version gives 1.5.0.6, i should say git version, not repository version. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You still haven't answered Tilman's first question. Your "Try 1" says you typed `git-init`, not `git init`.

Comment: I tried both actually. The usage statement is git-init. Sorry again. Correcting it.

Comment: Ok, I think, my version research wasn't correct. The `--bare` option was there for `git clone` since 1.2.0. `git init` takes it since 1.5.6. But there is a global `--bare` option since 1.4.2.
So, you could try `git --bare init sample.git`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, upgrade your git. Version 1.5 is positively ancient.

If you can't upgrade, I'd just create a normal git repository, then manually convert it to a bare repo.  An ordinary git repo will contain a '.git' directory. This can be your "bare" repo.  Rename this directory to whatever you like. (You'll probably want to `mv .git ../myrepo.git`).

Then you have to tell git that it is a bare repo. Do this by adding `bare = true` to the config file in the `[core]` configuration section.